# get the rank of an element of a boost::multi_index container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

The code below shows a multi_index container which is indexed by sequence and order.

In my use case elements will be mainly searched by index, and if existing, the next element (by order) is obtained.

My question is, how to get the rank (by order) of obtained next element?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ranked_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef multi_index_container <
    int
  , indexed_by<
        sequenced<>
      , ordered_non_unique<identity<int>>
      , ranked_non_unique<identity<int>>
    >
> Ints;

int main() {
    Ints ints;

    auto & sequence=ints.get<0>();
    auto & order=ints.get<1>();

    sequence.push_back(2);
    sequence.push_back(-1);
    sequence.push_back(5);
    sequence.push_back(6);

    auto it = order.find(2);
    if (it!=order.end()) {
        std::cout
            << "next to "
            << *it
            << " by sequence is "
            << *(++(ints.project<0>(it)))
            << std::endl
        ;
        std::cout
            << "next to "
            << *it
            << " by order is "
            << *(++(ints.project<1>(it))) //++it is good too
            << std::endl
        ;
        std::cout
            << "rank of next by sequence is "
            // << ??? ints.rank<???>(???)
            << std::endl
        ;
        std::cout
            << "rank of next by order is "
            // << ??? ints.rank<???>(???)
            << std::endl
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sehe's answer is perfectly valid but runs in linear time. If you want better performance, consider defining your index #0 as `random_access` and #1 as `ranked_non_unique` (index #2 is redundant):

```
typedef multi_index_container <
    int
  , indexed_by<
        random_access<>
      , ranked_non_unique<identity<int>>
    >
> Ints;
```

so that you can write:

```
std::cout
    << "rank of next by sequence is "
    << ints.project<0>(it)-sequence.begin()+1 // O(1)
    << std::endl
;
std::cout
    << "rank of next by order is "
    << order.rank(it)+1 // O(log n)
    << std::endl
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the performance hint. Indeed performance is critical (the containers size is several GB and will be queried multiple times per second). But I don't understand your change to random access. I need to combine std::set and std::vector. First to search via order (std::set) and than jump to the neighbour via sequence (std::vector).

Comment: `random_access` is needed if you need to quickly (O(1)) determine the rank of an element within this index (#0 in your example). If you're only interested in getting the rank according to its less-than order, then you need  a ranked index, which gives you that in O(log n) time. Note that the rank in index #0 is not the same as rank in index #1. I'm not sure I've answered your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want some kind of "index into" or "offset from begin" in the sequenced index:

```
if (it!=order.end()) {
    auto rank_of = [&](auto it) {
        return std::distance(sequence.begin(), ints.project<0>(it));
    };

    auto seq_next = std::next(seq_it);
    auto ord_next = std::next(it);

    if (seq_next!=sequence.end())
    {
        std::cout << "next to                     " << *it << " by sequence is " << *seq_next << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rank of next by sequence is " << rank_of(seq_next) << std::endl;
    }

    if (ord_next!=order.end())
    {
        std::cout << "next to                     " << *it << " by order is " << *ord_next << std::endl ;
        std::cout << "rank of next by order is    " << rank_of(ord_next) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Without polymorphic lambdas you should write it out